# Creating Empty list and doing some manipulation

Tags: python, regex, string

Here is what I am trying to do.
I have a list with strings as element inside it.Now I wanted to do more than 2 things with it.

1. Create Empty list inside the class.
2. Doing manipulation with every element in list and then adding it to the empyt list which I have created.

My code so far.

```
class aer(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = []
  def rem_digit(self,s):
    self.value.append(re.sub(" \d+"," ",s))
  def to_lower(self,s):
    self.value.append(self.s.lower())
```

It will be great if someone can point me the mistakes I am making.
And also how to access the "list" which I made inside the class.

Sample List:

```
mki = ["@tenSjunkie We're sorry for the inconvenience. Please call the Guest Service Desk using this link http://t.co/8Zv8DFwbbu and your receipt.",
 "@lindz_h We're sorry for the inconvenience. Please call the Guest Service Desk using this link http://t.co/Ak9fnazHZN and your receipt."]
```

Some improvement over last or rather say I was defeated in front of CLASS

```
def some_mani(old_list):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(old_list)):
        new_list.append(re.sub(" \d+"," ",old_list[i]).lower())
    return new_list
```

I am still wondering if someone help me to build this in CLASS.

Comment: `self.value.append(self.s.lower())` should be `self.value.append(s.lower())`

Comment: And how are you supposed to *use* this? What do you expect `self.value` to contain when you call your class methods?

Comment: Martijn please correct me if I am wrong. But I am trying to do the "Manipulation" like making "string" lower case or removing digits. These strings are elements of list so I am trying to get list as a result where elements will be string like earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble understanding exactly why you would ever want this, but it sounds like you want a class that contains a list of strings as well as some methods to do some simple string manipulation and add the results to that list. Based on that assumption, here is some code:

```
class MysteriousStringContainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []

    def remove_digits(self, s):
        self.values.append(re.sub("\d+", " ", s))

    def to_lower(self, s):
        self.values.append(s.lower())
```

Now you can initialize a MysteriousStringContainer and start calling its methods:

```
>>> m = MysteriousStringContainer()
>>> print m.values
[]
>>> for s in mki:
...     m.remove_digits(s)
...
>>> print m.values
["@tenSjunkie We're sorry for the inconvenience. Please call the Guest Service Desk using this link http://t.co/ Zv DFwbbu and your receipt.", "@lindz_h We're sorry for the inconvenience. Please call the Guest Service Desk using this link http://t.co/Ak fnazHZN and your receipt."]
```

As you can see, the digits have been removed and the resulting strings are available in `m.values`. Before you go on using this though, I have to stress that this is **almost certainly** a terrible way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. The code above would be written **much better** without the class wrapped around it:

```
>>> nodigits = re.sub("\d+", " ", mki[0])
>>> print nodigits
"@tenSjunkie We're sorry for the inconvenience. Please call the Guest Service Desk using this link http://t.co/ Zv DFwbbu and your receipt."
```

Here you still have the original strings in the `mki` list, and your new string with no digits is stored as the `nodigits` variable. I can't think of any reason to use a strange and un-intuitive class setup to obfuscate preexisting functionality, but if that's what you need to do, I think the code above will do it.

Comment: @BhupendrasinhThakre Yes it does. That (among other reasons) is why this is not a good way to do string manipulation. Why can't you assign values to your results the easy way, without the bizarre class and list contortions?

Comment: I think the approach you are suggesting me will be more suitable. Also I will try to do this through help of database classes available in python.